# How to get old rotated logs in Azure AKS Kubernetes (for Hyperledger Fabric peer nodes)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, azure-aks

I am running a Hyperledger Fabric network in Azure. I see that if I try to get logs of the fabric peer nodes using "kubectl logs..." command I only have the last 24 hours (aprox). AKS is probably rotating them. How can I get previous day logs of these pods?

Answer (score 0):

It dependes on the policy and configuration of your AKS service. If you want to get more logs, you can use [the since-time option](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/container_debugging/container_logs.html), to determine them, as you can see in this example:

```
kubectl logs nginx-78f5d695bd-czm8z --since-time=2018-11-01T15:00:00Z
```

On the other hand, you can also configure the LogAnalytics service of Azure and define a retentio policy to maintain your logs stored, as long as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried the since-time and since attributes but makes no change so I will check that LogAnalytics service in Azure.